# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed visual studio 2010 on my Inspiron 1464 64 bit processor which has windows 7 professional installed. I tried to install sql server 2008 r2 express edition with tools version 10.50.1600.1 from microsoft. But i am unable to install it i have got the following error in the middle of the installed and it closed.

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup

The following error has occurred:

The MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server. This is either because of a semantic error such as an incompatibility with the existing WMI repository or an actual error such as the failure of the WMI server to start.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1&EvtType=0xA60E3551%25400xD3BEBD98%25401211%25401

Here is the log file message of the above error.

> ```
>   Machine Properties:
>     Machine name:                  GHAFFAR-PC
>     Machine processor count:       4   OS version:                    Windows 7   OS service pack:                  OS region:
> ```
>
> United States   OS language:                   English (United States)
>   OS architecture:               x64   Process architecture:          64
>   Bit   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered
>   Sql Server 2008      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS
>   Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express
>   Edition      10.1.2531.0     No           Sql Server 2008
>   SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS             SQL Server
>   Replication                   1033                 Express Edition
>   10.1.2531.0     No
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   SQL Server
>   Database Services 2008 R2   ProductName:                   SQL Server
>   2008 R2   Type:                          RTM   Version:
>   10   SPLevel:                       0   Installation location:
>   d:\d2a7ae0724758063e2a9b4\x64\setup\   Installation edition:
>   EXPRESS_ADVANCED
>
> User Input Settings:   ACTION:                        Install
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      True   AGTSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
>   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled   ASBACKUPDIR:
>   Backup   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
>   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config   ASDATADIR:
>   Data   ASDOMAINGROUP:                    ASLOGDIR:
>   Log   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1   ASSVCACCOUNT:
>      ASSVCPASSWORD:                    ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:               ASTEMPDIR:
>   Temp   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
>   CUSOURCE:                         ENABLERANU:                    True 
>   ENU:                           True   ERRORREPORTING:
>   False   FARMACCOUNT:                      FARMADMINPORT:
>   0   FARMPASSWORD:                     FEATURES:
>   SQLENGINE,SSMS,SNAC_SDK   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
>   FILESTREAMSHARENAME:              FTSVCACCOUNT:
>      FTSVCPASSWORD:                    HELP:
>   False   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  False   INDICATEPROGRESS:
>   False   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             
>   INSTANCEDIR:                   D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ 
>   INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER   INSTANCENAME:
>   MSSQLSERVER   ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT
>   AUTHORITY\NetworkService   ISSVCPASSWORD:                 
>   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic   NPENABLED:
>   0   PASSPHRASE:                       PCUSOURCE:
>   PID:                              QUIET:
>   False   QUIETSIMPLE:                   False   ROLE:
>   AllFeatures_WithDefaults   RSINSTALLMODE:
>   FilesOnlyMode   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
>   SERVICE   RSSVCPASSWORD:                    RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   SAPWD:                            SECURITYMODE:
>      SQLBACKUPDIR:                     SQLCOLLATION:
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
>   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:
>   Ghaffar-PC\Ghaffar   SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:                  SQLUSERDBDIR:
>      SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:                  SQMREPORTING:
>   False   TCPENABLED:                    0   UIMODE:
>   AutoAdvance   X86:                           False
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20111222_105332\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:   Feature:                       Database Engine
>   Services   Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
>   MSI status:                    Passed   Configuration status:
>   Failed: see details below   Configuration error code:
>   0xD3BEBD98@1211@1   Configuration error description: The MOF compiler
>   could not connect with the WMI server. This is either because of a
>   semantic error such as an incompatibility with the existing WMI
>   repository or an actual error such as the failure of the WMI server to
>   start.
>        Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK   Status:                        Passed   MSI status:
>   Passed   Configuration status:          Passed
>
> Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic Status:
>   Failed: see logs for details   MSI status:                    Passed
>   Configuration status:          Failed: see details below
>   Configuration error code:      0xD3BEBD98@1211@1   Configuration error
>   description: The MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server.
>   This is either because of a semantic error such as an incompatibility
>   with the existing WMI repository or an actual error such as the
>   failure of the WMI server to start.    Rules with failures: Global
>   rules: Scenario specific rules:
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20111222_105332\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

I went to the above link for sorting out the error but nothing their. Can any buddy tell me how actually it would be cured?

Best regards,

Ghaffar

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem while installing **MS SQL Server 2017 Enterprise**.

I've used **[Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_installer_cleanup_utility.html)** (Microsoft product) to remove everything associated with SQL server. This tool listed tone of components and apps from SQL Server which I didn't see in Control Panel - Uninstall Software option.

I could select all SQL programs and start uninstall procedure for all of them. This tool is really effective.
I was able to install MS SQL Server 2017 Enterprise successfully after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with yours but was able to solved it by uninstalling the Sql server completely using CCleaner to uninstall it.
Try to uninstall using control panel might not uninstall all the files necessary.

Turn off the windows firewall.
Then reinstall the sql server.