# Unable to install SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am unable to install SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition on Windows 10 Pro.

Below is the error which I keep getting even after troubleshooting steps that were taken by Google suggestions. Can somebody have a look and help me to proceed?

> Error description: The MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server. This is either because of a semantic error such as an incompatibility with the existing WMI repository or an actual error such as the failure of the WMI server to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the solution here: [mof compiler problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600158/microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-setup-mof-compiler-could-not-connect-with-the-wmi-s)

Also, consider using a Docker Container instead of a native installation

Comment: Hi user1443098, I've gone through the link "mof compiler problem" and SQL Server Installation has been succeeded in windows 10 machine.  I have got issue back ground that previous versions of sql server files were not cleaned completely and to do this I used Windows Installer CleanUp Utility.

Comment: Cool!  These days, though, I reach for docker first.  Keeps my installed software list a little shorter.And no worries about side-effects or dependencies or additional processes when I'm not using the container